# Thead Dump Java SE scheduled Application stuck issue

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, network-programming, eclipselink

I have java SE jar file running on the windows server. Application process some record and the commits the record on the database and for that i am using ORM toll eclipselink.Application is scheduled to run on intervals. The problem i am facing is that application stucks after one or two days running and processing is stopped.Following is the full thread dump when application got stuck. If any one who could read that dump and help me out.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing):
"DestroyJavaVM" prio=6 tid=0x0095b000 nid=0x5ce8 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
"pool-1-thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x049a4800 nid=0x5a1c runnable [0x041ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:706)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:228)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:361)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:151)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:595)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:380)
        - locked <0x24306260> (a org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
        - locked <0x24390e88> (a org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
        at com.warid.bs.posttoprebalanceshare.PostToPreBalnaceShareTask.run(PostToPreBalnaceShareTask.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x01fb8400 nid=0x386c runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01fb3800 nid=0x37e4 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01fb2c00 nid=0x5f30 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01fa8000 nid=0x748 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x01f93800 nid=0x15b4 in Object.wait() [0x0445f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x296ccd30> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x296ccd30> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01f92000 nid=0x296c in Object.wait() [0x042ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x296cc8f8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x296cc8f8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01f90c00 nid=0x3210 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01fd2c00 nid=0x5d78 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 301

Heap
 def new generation   total 33984K, used 5349K [0x24170000, 0x26640000, 0x296c0000)
  eden space 30272K,   8% used [0x24170000, 0x243d0ad8, 0x25f00000)
  from space 3712K,  78% used [0x262a0000, 0x26578990, 0x26640000)
  to   space 3712K,   0% used [0x25f00000, 0x25f00000, 0x262a0000)
 tenured generation   total 75280K, used 50183K [0x296c0000, 0x2e044000, 0x34170000)
   the space 75280K,  66% used [0x296c0000, 0x2c7c1c18, 0x2c7c1e00, 0x2e044000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10668K [0x34170000, 0x34d70000, 0x38170000)
   the space 12288K,  86% used [0x34170000, 0x34bdb1a8, 0x34bdb200, 0x34d70000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38170000, 0x385b4240, 0x385b4400, 0x38b70000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38b70000, 0x391f4d58, 0x391f4e00, 0x39770000)
```

Comment: As stated in an answer, it is not 'stuck' in the JVM, but it is waiting on data from the database.  EclipseLink is trying to create a persistence unit and connect to the database, and this is what is not returning or taking a large amount of time.  Check your connection settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is stuck in your application. Your application thread *pool-1-thread-1* is actually busy querying your database:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:706)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:228)
```

I'd rather check your database.

Comment: Hi benjamin, if thread is ruuning then why he is not able to query the database.While i restart the application it runs properly.

Comment: Hi, it is running, and waiting on the database to send back results